# Should I delete my question?

Tags: discussion

I posted this question:

[Automatic Weights not recalculating after moving Bone](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140826/automatic-weights-not-recalculating-after-moving-bone/140836#140836)

While I think it's a valid question, it is kind of a duplicate. I just realized that this behavior is happening because my vertex groups were **locked** on my mesh, which kept them from being updated.

As such, the question I link to in the post solves my problem. However, I still think it might be valuable knowledge to provide this information regarding unlocked vertex groups, especially since I think that the nature/function of Blender may draw its fair share of newbies like myself.

Answer (score 8):

Unless the question is not valid, **please don't delete your posts**. Duplicates are valuable, they might help other users get to the information they need. Deleting a question will only make it harder for those who might have a similar issue.

**Deleting a post will also make answers inaccessible**. As a sign of gratitude and respect to those users who tried to help you (given the time they spent researching, writing, creating images, projects or links), consider leaving their answers up, don't let their efforts go to waste. Keep in mind that all contributors to this site are volunteering their time and sharing what they've learnt.

Additionally, if you found a solution to your own question, even if it is a mix of the content of other posts, please write up an answer. Others might benefit from your experience.

Answer (score 4):

> However, I still think it might be valuable knowledge to provide this information regarding unlocked vertex groups

That's merit enough to keep it. I'd also suggest linking to any similar posts you chanced across since you feel it's a dupe of sorts. If it is an exact duplicate of an existing post it can be marked as such.